# Como acceder a la ruta o carpeta desde donde se abre el archivo? PHP

Tags: php

Tengo una consulta, estoy tratando de acceder a mi carpeta **reviews** para acceder al archivo **global_variables.php** que está en la ruta:

> C:/xampp/htdocs/easycryptos/public_html/sitios/brokers-regulados/avatrade/reviews/global_variables.php

Este archivo **global_variables.php** lo estoy llamando desde un archivo *.php* que está en la ruta:

> /includes/submit_rating.php.

El **submit_rating.php** es un archivo que se usa en todas las páginas y *busco la manera de incluir en el submit_rating.php unas variables*, de acuerdo a la carpeta desde donde se abra.

En el ejemplo  expuesto arriba las variables están en

> avatrade/reviews/global_variables.php

**avatrade** es una de las carpetas hay varias de diferentes sitios a los que se les escribirán reseñas.

Lo que estoy usando es:

```php
$URL= ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])."/global_variables.php");
echo $URL;
```

y esto me devuelve

> C:/xampp/htdocs/easycryptos/public_html/sitios/brokers-regulados/avatrade/reviews/index.php/global_variables.php

**¿Cómo podría lograr tener el resultado de**

> C:/xampp/htdocs/easycryptos/public_html/sitios/brokers-regulados/avatrade/reviews/global_variables.php

Agradezco cualquier idea.

### ACTUALIZACIÓN:

Estoy haciendo un sistema de reseñas, cuyas variables globales están en el archivo **global_variables.php**. Aquí están definidas las variables para cada sitio web a reseñar. La estructura del sitio está así:

```
/includes/submit_rating.php
/sitios/algunsitio/reviews/global_variables.php
```

en el **submit_rating.php** debo llamar las variables del archivo **global_variables.php** para ejecutar el script

```php
<?php

//submit_rating.php
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/includes/conexion.php");
$URL = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])."/global_variables.php";
$URL = getcwd()."/global_variables.php";
 echo $URL; 
include ($URL);

if(isset($_POST["rating_data"]))
{
     $var = $_POST['user_email'];
     $emailfor = strtolower($var);
     

    $data = array(
    
        ':lang'             =>  $lang,
        ':page_id'          =>  $page_id,
        ':user_name'        =>  $_POST["user_name"],
        ':user_email'       =>  $emailfor,
        ':user_rating'      =>  $_POST["rating_data"],
        ':user_review'      =>  $_POST["user_review"],
        ':user_avatar'      =>  $_POST["user_avatar"],
        
    );

$sql=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM avatrade WHERE lang='$lang' AND page_id='$page_id' AND user_email='$emailfor'");

?>
```

Las variables **lang** y **page_id** están declaradas en **global_variables.php**

Cuando uso el ejemplo del compañero me imprime la ruta deseada, pero al llamar el **submit_rating.php** me lee como si estuviera buscando en la carpeta **/includes/global_variables.php**

Comment: en alguna parte llamas directamente a `submit_rating.php` o siempre es via `include`?

Comment: y segundo, por qué no puedes incluir las global variables en el index de avatrade de antemano?

Comment: El submit_rating lo incluyo en el Index ya que en el Index de avatrade hay un script que por petición post se ejecuta. Para  tu segundo comentario no pongo las variables globales en el Index de avatrade para que no quede tan cargado

Comment: aclaro mis preguntas: "1. podemos asumir entonces que por browser sólo cargas el respectivo index de cada broker y nunca cargas directo (ni por ajax, ni por iframe, ni por form) algo de la carpeta includes?" y "2. no me refiero a copiar y pegar el contenido, sino sólo a `include(__DIR__.'/global_variables.php')` justo antes de donde hoy tienes, imagino `include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/includes/submit_rating.php");`